# Self-join Queries for hierarchical data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, self-join

I'm having difficulty in understanding the question below:

> Find the names of all skills directly required by the skills required by a skill C++ Programming. > (E.g. C++ Programming requires C Programming and C Programming requires reading and writing).

The table `SREQUIRED` is given as below:
[image]
[image]

The SQL query I did was:

```
SELECT 
    s1.requires 
FROM 
    srequired s1
    INNER JOIN
    srequired s2 
ON 
    s1.sname = s2.requires
    AND
    s2.sname = 'C++ programming';
```

NOTE: The solution must be implemented using `self-join`.

Am I doing it right? I'm using `SQL Plus` and `Oracle DB`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`CONNECT BY PRIOR` is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT sname,
       requires,
       LEVEL
FROM srequired
START WITH sname = 'C++ programming' CONNECT BY
PRIOR sname = requires
ORDER SIBLINGS BY sname;
```

Read more of Hierarchical Queries here: [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

For cross-DBMS using SELF JOIN: [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/)

Comment: thanks but the question required us to use self-join query.

Comment: @Zackery A normal self-join query won't work here unless the number of levels in the hierarchy has a predefined limit.  Or perhaps if the definition of "self-join query" includes recursive subquery factoring.

Comment: @Zackery: This question is much more complicated than it looks like. Please see the link I added in the updated answer.